# Call custom module API in magento2

Tags: magento2, api, custom

I have installed a module that allowing to upload attachment to products. But I have to do this pro-grammatically via my other custom module. 
installed module have API function in it. But I don't know how to call these API function in Magento-2.

As API file `Api/ProductAttachmentRepositoryInterface.php` have function -

`public function save(Data\ProductAttachmentInterface $productAttachment);`

And respective file at location Data/ProductAttachmentInterface.php have following code . That have some variable declaration, get/set function.

```
`namespace Companyname\ProductAttachment\Api\Data;

interface ProductAttachmentInterface
{
    const ID = 'id';
    const PRODUCT_ID = 'product_id';
    const FILE_PATH = 'file_path';
    const FILE_NAME = 'file_name';
    const FILE_URL = 'file_url';
    const FILE_SIZE = 'file_size';
    const FILE_TYPE = 'file_type';

    const FILE_TYPE_FILE = 'file';
    const FILE_TYPE_URL = 'url';

    const CUSTOMER_GROUP = 'customer_group';
    const STORE_CONFIG = 'store_config';

    const CONTENT = 'content';

    public function getId();


    public function getProductId();

    //public function getFilePath();


    public function getFileName();public function setId($id);
`
```

Here I am bit confuse.....what I need to pass as parameter and which function I should call and how  ?

Please help me on this...